# Template Tag requires 0 arguments, 1 provided

Tags: django

Why can't I create a template tag with an argument like this?

```
@register.filter
def foo(value, arg):
    return arg
```

And I am calling it like this:

```
{{ params|foo:"bar" }}
```

Which gives me:
`foo requires 0 arguments, 1 provided`

Comment: Do you possibly have another filter called "foo" somewhere else?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams No. Tried renaming it as well already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to it using something called coffin tags, that is some old version of a binding between Jinja and Django.